# How to change data with different datetime formats to datetime column of another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL table with one varchar data type column, having dates in different formats.

Example Data:

```
2017-06-30 09:40:05.130,  
2017-08-21 12:52:23.063000000,  
26/4/2016 00:00:00,  
5/4/2016 00:00:00
```

I have a requirement to load data from this column(varchar data type) to another SQL table column with datetime data type.
I tried the following query

```
Select 
convert(datetime,convert(char(19),'2017-08-21 12:52:23.063000000'))

Select 
convert(datetime,convert(char(19),'26/4/2016 00:00:00'),103)
```

Can anybody help me a common single query which converts different format dates ?

Comment: Your second entry is in an interesting format... even `DATETIME2` will only give you 7 places past the decimal point, you have 9.

Comment: There isn't a way to get any string representation of a date into an actual datetime that works for any string. This is one reason why dates should never be stored as strings. You are probably going to have to do this in groups. Find those that fit one format and convert those, then other groups one by one. Then there will be the last group....the "I don't know what to do with this because it isn't a date" group.

Comment: basically I am getting these dates from different source csv files ,loading them into stage table initially with varchar datatype.then trying to load to another table of datetime datatype.The csv source files are having different formats in each file.

Comment: As I pointed out below, `26/4/2016 00:00:00` will require different handling. The rest seem okay with a `CONVERT`, with the exception of your second example where precision MAY be lost to that level. Emphasis on MAY, because I've tried it in SQL Server 2014, and it worked okay, as you can see in my example below.

Answer (score 0):

It's an ugly task, but this is the best I can think of:

```
select convert(datetime2, '9/20/2017')
select convert(datetime2, '2017-06-30 09:40:05.130')
select convert(datetime2, '2017-08-21 12:52:23.063000000')
select convert(datetime, '5/4/2016 00:00:00')
```

However, keep in mind, as @Eli pointed out in the comments, your second example might miss precession. Also, it won't handle '26/4/2016 00:00:00'.

The above examples will return as follows (in same order):

```
2017-09-20 00:00:00.0000000
2017-06-30 09:40:05.1300000
2017-08-21 12:52:23.0630000
2016-05-04 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried following query ,it worked for me for different formats in my case

```
declare @col varchar(100)='2017-08-21 12:52:23.063000000'

Select 
    case 
        when isdate(convert(char(19),@col))=1 then convert(datetime,convert(char(19),@col)) 
        else convert(datetime,convert(char(19),@col),103) 
    end Col
```

I tried with all above date, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use error handling to ignore failed conversions, so you also need a cursor to handle each row of data. That way you manipulate values that can be converted and handle any way you see fit values that cannot be converted, without having your loop interrupted by conversion error. A small example:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (dat NVARCHAR(64))
INSERT INTO @tbl (dat) VALUES ('2017-06-30 09:40:05.130')
INSERT INTO @tbl (dat) VALUES ('26/4/2016 00:00:00')
INSERT INTO @tbl (dat) VALUES ('2017-08-21 12:52:23.063000000')
INSERT INTO @tbl (dat) VALUES ('5/4/2016 00:00:00')
DECLARE @cdat NVARCHAR(64)

DECLARE c CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR 
    SELECT dat FROM @tbl
OPEN c
FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @cdat
WHILE @@fetch_status = 0 BEGIN 

    BEGIN TRY  
        /*convert and do the job*/
        SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2,@cdat)--into normal table
    END TRY  
    BEGIN CATCH  
        /*handle failed conversions*/
        SELECT @cdat --into failstable?
        PRINT 'failed conversion, data:' + @cdat
    END CATCH  

    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @cdat
END 
CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL server 2012 or above, you can use `TRY_PARSE` function.
This is not a SQL Native function rather it is a .NET runtime dependent function. It also facilitates to parse data culture wise which not there in `TRY_CONVERT` and `TRY_CAST`. It may create performance overhead but it tries its best to parse the data to specified data type.

```
declare @t table (dates nvarchar(50));
insert into @t values
('2017-06-30 09:40:05.130'), 
('2017-08-21 12:52:23.063000000'),  
('26/4/2016 00:00:00'),  
('5/4/2016 00:00:00') ;

select  
    try_parse(dates as datetime)  parsed_dates ,
    dates 
from @t;

--result

    parsed_dates        dates
    30.06.2017 09:40:05 2017-06-30 09:40:05.130
    21.08.2017 12:52:23 2017-08-21 12:52:23.063000000
    NULL                26/4/2016 00:00:00
    04.05.2016 00:00:00 5/4/2016 00:00:00
```

[**`see demo`**](http://rextester.com/AIKCQ17934)